# Generate random sequences from dataframe information in python

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

I try to generate random sequences to test a software, but I got stuck. Basically I read a dataframe from CSV like this:

```
      HG  mut
0     A1    7
1    A1a    5
2    A1b   10
3    A1c   15
4   A1a1   18
5   A1b1   21
6  A1a1a   12
```

HG column is the name of the sequence, the mut column is how many numbers should it a list have. Right now my code is this:

```
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    globals()["pos_" + str(data.HG[i])] = random.sample(range(1, 30000), data.mut[i])
```

It's generate the perfect sequences, but my problem is, that somehow I have to go through the HG column, and if a name is in an another (for example A1a is in A1), it should contain it's own sequences, and the higher level sequences too. For example:
A1a1a contains it's own sequences, A1-A1a-A1a1 sequences.
How could i do it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: That is not acceptable Python code.  Any time you use globals(), you are doing it wrong.  You can store those in a dict, as in `pos[data.HG[i]] = random.sample(...)`.  So, are you saying you want to create a new dataframe with a new column that has the sums you mention?

Comment: Thank you Tim! Right now I store the different HG's sequences in the dict according to dataframe index. Next step to check, if nth HG contains others or not, and add that sequence to them, if yes.